# In any metric space X, the sets ∅ and X are always closed.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

In any metric space X, the sets ∅ and X are always closed.

Hello, I need help in proving this statement. I'm not exactly sure where to start. I have tried to teach myself the definitions, however it hasn't been successful. In class, we have only learned about closed sets.

Can you please walk me through this proof/ how to approach this problem? I'd really like to know how to use the definitions and understand the logic.

Comment: What is the definition of closed sets you learned?

Comment: Let A be a subset of X. The set A is closed in X if A contains all of its accumulation points in X.

Comment: Please check the tag descriptions before you use them; I've removed several really irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The empty set has no accumulation points, so it contains all of its accumulation points vacuously. The set $X$ may have many accumulation points. Suppose that $x$ is an accumulation point of $X$. Since $x$ is a point, it must be a member of the universal space $X$. Therefore, $X$ contains all of its accumulation points.

Comment: Can you expand on the second part?

Comment: I made an edit. Basically, $X$ is all we know about. Any accumulation point we may use exists relative to the universal set we are working in. But in this case, the universal set *is* $X$. So every point we talk about has to be inside of $X$. In particular, all accumulation points of any subset of $X$ is in $X$, even if that subset is $X$ itself.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Often a closed set is defined as a set whose complement is open, while an open set is defined as a set in which all points are interior. If this is how you defined it, the empty set is open vacuously, so $X$ is closed. Every point of $X$ is in the interior of $X$ since trivially any ball only intersects points of $X$. Thus $X$ is open, so the empty set is closed.

But of course, the solution depends on how your particular text defined these terms.

Comment: Wow I must be tired.

Comment: I personally *very* much prefer the definition is a set containing all its limit points.  They're equivalent as the compliment being open means every point of the compliment has a neighbor entirely in the compliment which means the point can not be a limit point.

Comment: I think the limit point definition is more useful to an analyst while in topology one prefers to define things in terms of the collection of open sets.

Answer (score 0):

There are two equivalent definition of closed.

1) A is closed if its compliment is open.  A set is open if every point is in interior point.

The compliment of X is the empty set.  The empty set has no points.  So every single one of the zero points is an interior point so the empty set is open. So X is closed.

The compliment of the empty set is X.  An interior point is on that has a neighborhood entirely in the set.  X is the entire space so *everything* is entirely in X including every neighborhood of every point.  So every point in X is an interior point of X so X is open and the empty set is closed.

2) a set is closed if every one of its limit points is in the set. A limit point is one in which every neighborhood has a point of the set (that is not the point itself).

The empty set has no points so no neighborhood can have any point of the empty set so no point can be a limit point of the empty set.  So the empty set has no limit points.  So all zero of them are in the empty set so the empty set is closed.

X meanwhile is the entire space so *everything* in the space is in it, so every limit point is in X because every point of X is in X so any limit points (if any exist) are in X.  So X is closed.